# Angular 5 select and unselect a checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox

Alright I have a terms of service modal which is an ngBootstrap modal and when I press the button to close that button I want the action that closes the modal define wheter the checkbox is checked or not
This is the html:

```
  <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Terms of service.</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross 
  click')">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="c('Close click'); 
   setAccepted(true)" >I accept.</button>
  </ng-template>
```

the link to open the modal and the checkbox

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input *ngIf="accepted" type="checkbox" class="custom-
control-input" id="save-info" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="save-info">I have read 
</label><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="open(content)"> 
  the terms of service</a>.
</div>
```

And under it I have  `<p>{{accepted}}</p>` just for testing

And the typescript

```
accepted: boolean = false;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

open(content) {
 this.modalService.open(content);
}

setAccepted(accepted:boolean){
  this.accepted = accepted;
}
```

I tried [(ngModel)], *ngIf, ngModel to the accepted boolean from my typescript but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you trying to check the checkbox?
That is not possible with `*ngIf="accepted"`?

Comment: Yes I want to check and uncheck it, but to keep it simple I only put the code I have to check it here. I tried [(ngModel)]="accepted" first but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is the checkbox inside of a `form` container?

Comment: yes it is but why does that matter?

Comment: In that case, `[(ngModel)]` must have caused an error (visible in the console) when trying to load the modal. It should work, however, if you also add a name attribute to the checkbox: `<input name="chkAccepted" [(ngModel)]="accepted" ...>`. That is the appropriate way to use two-way data binding with a checkbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "[checked]" input propery or attribute.
Use a Boolean to check on uncheck the checkbox.

In Template:

```
    <input [checked]="accepted" type="checkbox" class="custom-
control-input" id="save-info" required>
```

In TS:

```
accepted: Boolean;
accepted = true;   // Or False
```

Comment: i noticed that if i run myForm.reset() method it doesn't uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: this does not work, except on page load

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, one comment...  You have...

```
 <button type="button" 
 class="btn btn-success" 
 (click)="c('Close click')" 
(click)="setAccepted(true)" >I accept.</button>
```

Should be

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
 (click)="c('Close click');setAccepted(true)" >I accept.</button>
```

At least this is how I do this for a button click, you can not have two separate (click) .  I have used this to success on my own personal site.

Comment: My bad just a copy paste issue but thanks I'll fix it, works tho have used it with angular 2 a year ago when I tried it out.

Comment: Interesting, I will have to try it myself then.   Then that would certainly not be the solution you're looking for... (damn thinking droids)..   I may avoid the common keyword "open" is my only sub comment.. I'd just comment on your original but no rep to do so ..   Pesky bug, I'd attempt also to put console log messages in each method, with the values printed

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now but I believe it used to work but not that I look at it again it does not seem logical that it still would.